# If $|{z}|=\max\big\{|{z}+2|,|{z}-2|\big\}$, then which is true: $|z\pm \bar{z}|=2$ or $|z\pm \bar{z}|=1/2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification, absolute-value

If $|{z}|=\max\big\{|{z}+2|,|{z}-2|\big\}$, then

(a) $|{z}-\bar{z}|=1 / 2$.

(b) $|{z}+\overline{{z}}|={2}$.

(c) $|{z}+\overline{{z}}|=1 / 2$.

$({d})|{z}-\overline{{z}}|={2}$.

---

**My approach**

$|z|=|z+2|$
$\Rightarrow {z\overline{z}}=({z}+2)(\overline{{z}}+2)$

$\Rightarrow {z}+{\overline{z}}=-2 \Rightarrow|{z}+{\overline{z}}|=2$

$|z|=|z-2| \Rightarrow z \bar{z}=(z-2)(\bar{z}-2)$

$\Rightarrow {z}+\overline{{z}}=2 \Rightarrow|{z}+\overline{{z}}|=2$

I guess it is right.
*My question is how can I  come to solution using any graphical approach!*

*for ref*:- https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nnnnairelh

Comment: There is no such $z$ that satisfies this equation.

Comment: @PeterForeman  Therefore, all options are correct.  I think the question contains a typo.  Perhaps, they want $|z|=\min\big\{|z+2|,|z-2|\big\}$.

Answer (score 1):

For a geometric approach:

$$|z|=|z-2|$$ is the equation of the **bissector of the segment with ends $0$ and $2.$**
Its equation can be written $\Re(z)=1.$
It is not excluded that the author of the MCQ was thinking of such approach.

BUT:

- If the real part satisfies $\Re(z)<0$ then the distance from $z$ to $2$ is greater than the distance to $-2.$
  In other words, $|z-2|$ is the maximum. However, $|z|=|z-2|$ is the above mentionned bissector and lies in the half-plane with positive real parts.
- If $\Re(z)>0,$ we arrive to a similar contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If

$$
|z|=\max\left(|z+2|,|z-2|\right)\Rightarrow 1 = \max\left(|1+2/z|,|1-2/z|\right)
$$

but

$$
\max\left(|1+2/z|,|1-2/z|\right) \gt 1
$$